# Convert a string that is formatted as JSONObject into a proper JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I currently have a string that is currently formatted as a giant JSONObject.

```
string bodyOutput = "{"type":"type1","content":"content1"},{"type":"type2","content":"content2"},{"type":"type3","content":"content3"}";
```

How can I format this string and turn it into a proper JSONObject?

If I try the following below, it will only grab the first value of the "string"

```
JSONObject bodyObj = new JSONObject(bodyOutput)
bodyObj = "{"type":"type1","content":"content1"}";
```

Thanks

Comment: your string is not a json object. it is a list of json objects separated by comas.

Comment: You may wrap your string into "[" .... "]" - so it will be JSON object